# How to disable a datepicker control in C# /Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I have date picker Control and the control is being used at many pages. I am just wondering how can I disable my date picker at one instance.

Here is date picker :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DatePicker.ascx.cs" Inherits="User_Controls_DatePicker" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd MMM yyyy"
    TargetControlID="TxtUCtrl_Date" BehaviorID="<%# TxtUCtrl_Date.ClientID %>" />
<cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="WatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TxtUCtrl_Date"
    WatermarkText="" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked input-mandatory">
</cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtUCtrl_Date" Width="100px" Height="14px"></asp:TextBox>
<input runat="server" id="BtnSelect" type="button" style="width: 40px" value="" />
```

And I am using this date picker as

```
<DatePicker:DatePicker ID="dtSupBookedFromDate" runat="server" ButtonText="Open Calendar"
                DateFormat="dd MMM yyyy" WatermarkText="Select Date" />
```

I found some solutions like I can add an `attribute` to the `textbox` for the purpose. one those links: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1429400.aspx

Can't we disable a date-picker using its ID (in my case `dtSupBookedFromDate` ).
I hope I'll get here a better solution...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that a Custom Control? If so, you need to add a public property in it's code behind that will get or set the readonly property of the textbox of your calendar.

```
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return WatermarkExtender1.ReadOnly; }
        set { WatermarkExtender1.ReadOnly = value; }
    }
```

Then you can set it like `dtSupBookedFromDate.ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: yes its a custom, and possibly adding a property to the control can work. Thanks.
but for the time i am going to use findcontrol property, coz i can't change the control.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's way may be a better one. This time I can't play with the custom control so going for find text box approach :(

```
TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)dtSupBookedFromDate.FindControl("TxtUCtrl_Date");
txtDate.Enabled = false;
```